# Additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN)

Tags: normal-distribution, signal-processing, image-processing, noise

In my research work regarding wireless communication, I came across many research papers wherein AWGN is assumed to be modelled as "**complex Gaussian with zero mean and unit variance**".

I understood why we model noise as Gaussian, but I am not getting why we model noise with zero mean and unit variance only.

Also, what effect the noise will make if mean is non-zero and variance is more than unity ?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We can be pretty sure that those wireless communication engineers do not only use AWGN with zero mean and unit variance. Similarly, nobody in elementary probability is only using the standard normal distribution. Shift it to change the mean, scale it to change its variance.